# activerecord validation - validates_associated

Tags: validation, activerecord, validates-associated

I'm unclear on what this method actually does or when to use it.

Lets say I have these models:

```
Person < ...
  # id, name
  has_many :phone_numbers
end

PhoneNumber < ...
  # id, number
  belongs_to :person
  validates_length_of :number, :in => 9..12    
end
```

When I create phone numbers for a person like this:

```
@person = Person.find(1)
@person.phone_numbers.build(:number => "123456")
@person.phone_numbers.build(:number => "12346789012")
@person.save
```

The save fails because the first number wasn't valid.   This is a good thing, to me.  But what I don't understand is if its already validating the associated records **what is the function validates_associated?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do `has_many :phone_numbers, validate: false` and the validation you're seeing wouldn't happen.

Why use `validates_associated` then? You might want to do `validates_associated :phone_numbers, on: :create` and skip validation on update (e.g. if there was already bad data in your db and you didn't want to hassle existing users about it).

There are other scenarios. `has_one` according to docs is `validate: false` by default. So you need `validates_associated` to change that.